# AngularJs filter not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to make a nice angularJS grid with boxes and a filter on the top where you pick which types you want. I have not been able to figure out why it doesn't work for me, I tried [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Au8KFg) and it worked but I wasn't able to apply it to my code.

Anyway, please read through it and help

```
 var ts = [{area:"area1", model:"500", color:"black", colspan: 3,rowspan: 3}, {area:"area2", model:"500", color:"red", colspan: 3,rowspan: 3}];
    var filtered= [];
    var areas = []
     for (var i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {
             if (!areas.includes(ts[i].area)){   
                areas.push(ts[i].area);
     }}
     angular
        .module('Application', ['ngMaterial'])
        .controller('gridController', gridController)


     function gridController ($scope) {
        $scope.filterAreas = { area:"area1" };
         $scope.dataDifferenceArray = [];
         $scope.areas= areas;


         $scope.filt = function(){
         console.log("gg");
          $scope.filterAreas = { area:"area2" };


             };
        $scope.colorTiles =ts
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="filterController" ng-controller="gridController as ctrl" style="max-height=500px" ng-cloak>
       <div id="filters" ng-repeat="x in areas"  ng-class="{'selected': clicked}" ng-click="clicked = !clicked;filt();">{{x}}</div>
</div>
  <div id="gridContainer" ng-controller="gridController as ctrl" ng-cloak>

     <md-content layout-padding style="clear: both;">
        <md-grid-list
           md-cols-gt-md="9" md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="6"
           md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3"
           md-gutter-gt-md="16px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px" md-gutter="4px">
           <md-grid-tile

              ng-class="{'flipped': clicked}" ng-click="clicked = !clicked"
              ng-repeat="tile in colorTiles | filter:filterAreas"
              md-colspan-gt-sm="{{tile.colspan}}"
              md-rowspan-gt-sm="{{tile.rowspan}}">
              <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
                 <div class="front face" style="background-color: tile.color !important;" ng-style="{
                    'background': tile.color
                    }">
                    <div >
                       <a>
                       some stuff
                       </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="back face center" style="background-color: tile.color !important;" ng-style="{
                    'background': tile.color
                    }">
                    <div style= "position: relative;">
                       <a >
                       some stuff
                       </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
     </md-content>
  </div>
```

`

Thank you!